How to Add Google Analytics to Astro Starlight Theme Without Layouts or Components Folder
Question:
I'm trying to add Google Analytics to my website built with the Astro Starlight theme. However, the theme doesn't have a layouts or components folder, which is where most tutorials suggest placing the tracking code.
Here are the steps I've taken so far:
Obtained my Google Analytics tracking ID (e.g., UA-XXXXX-Y).
Tried to locate files in the theme where I can insert the tracking code.
The structure of the Astro Starlight theme is different from what I'm used to, and I'm not sure where to add the Google Analytics tracking script.
Can anyone guide me on how to properly integrate Google Analytics with the Astro Starlight theme?
Additional Information:
I'm using the latest version of the Astro Starlight theme.
The theme doesn't have obvious layouts or components directories.
I need a way to include the tracking code in a way that works with this specific theme structure.
Thanks in advance for your help!

The Starlight docs have this example of the head config field. Put the following into astro.config.mjs:
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';
import starlight from '@astrojs/starlight';

export default defineConfig({
  integrations: [
    starlight({
      head: [
        // Example: add Fathom analytics script tag.
        {
          tag: 'script',
          attrs: {
            src: 'https://cdn.usefathom.com/script.js',
            'data-site': 'MY-FATHOM-ID',
            defer: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
});

which will put the following HTML in the document's <head>:
<script
  src="https://cdn.usefathom.com/script.js" 
  data-site="MY-FATHOM-ID"
  defer
  >
</script>

Adjust accordingly for Google Analytics.

You can add the following in astro.config.mjs:
const googleAnalyticsId = '<YOUR-GOOGLE-ID>'
...
export default defineConfig({
  ...
  integrations: [
    starlight({
      ...
      head: [
        // Adding google analytics
        {
          tag: 'script',
          attrs: {
            src: `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${googleAnalyticsId}`,
          },
        },
        {
          tag: 'script',
          content: `
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
          gtag('js', new Date());

          gtag('config', '${googleAnalyticsId}');
          `,
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
});

